# Bokeh how to load a file with its directory?

Tags: python-3.x, input, bokeh

I am trying to get the file to work in bokeh. When using the `input` widget, it only gives me the filename. How to make a file name with a directory, when opening the file there were no errors?

```
csvfile = FileInput() # csvfile = ('C:/matlab0012.csv')
csvopen = myfun(csvfile) # myfun-my function that creates graphs from data from a file
```

Answer (score 1):

@bigreddot is right. you cannot get full path. but you can reach selected file. However, you have to decode it first.

minimal example :

```
from pybase64 import b64decode

def get_file(attr, old, new):
    file = io.BytesIO(b64decode(new))
    new_data = pd.read_csv(file)  # pandas or just use open.

file_input = FileInput(name="fileinput", accept="<.csv>")
file_input.on_change('value', get_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. For security reasons, browsers will not provide the full path. They will only provide the filename and the file contents from the file that was requested.

Assuming those is a Bokeh server application, you can only respond to a file selection with an `on_change` callback that you add to the `value` property of the `input` widget.

If this is standalone output (not Bokeh server) then you can only respond with a JavaScript `js_on_change` callback since the Bokeh content displayed in the browser is not connected to any Python process.

In either case, all that the browser will provide is the file contents (which Bokeh stores as base64 encoded strings in the `value` property).